# Redux CombineReducers returns defaultState after every action that is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

well I had a single reducer and I split it to multiple reducers.When the reducer was one everything was working good, but now , every time an action dispatches, makes the previous changes to state back to default. I don't really know what is happening this has no logic. For an example

This is one out of five reducers, and the other reducers are like that.

```
const initState = { name: null || "You", gameOn: false, homePage: true };
const navigationReducer = (state = initState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "GET_USER_NAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        name: payload.name
      };

    case "SETTING_GAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        gameOn: true,
        homePage: false
      };

    case "GO_TO_HOME":
      return {
        ...state,
        homePage: true,
        gameOn: false,
        name: null || "You"
      };

    case "RESET":
      return { ...state, name: null || "You", gameOn: false, homePage: true };

    default:
      return initState;
  }
};

export default navigationReducer;
```

And here in Index.js I export the rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import navigationReducer from "./navigationReducer";
import deckReducer from "./deckReducer";
import gameReducer from "./gameReducer";
import bidReducer from "./bidReducer";
import winnerReducer from "./winnerReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navigation: navigationReducer,
  deck: deckReducer,
  game: gameReducer,
  bid: bidReducer,
  winner: winnerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

After that i configure the store like this

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from "redux-observable";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

import {
  gamePreparationEpic,
  deckIsReadyEpic,
  serveHandsToPlayersEpic,
  evaluateHandsEpic,
  findTheWinnerEpic,
  resetGameEpic,
  cardIsSelectedEpic,
  fillCardsEpic,
  cpuBidEpic
} from "../epics";

const configureStore = () => {
  const epicsArr = [
    gamePreparationEpic,
    deckIsReadyEpic,
    serveHandsToPlayersEpic,
    evaluateHandsEpic,
    findTheWinnerEpic,
    resetGameEpic,
    cardIsSelectedEpic,
    fillCardsEpic,
    cpuBidEpic
  ];
  const epics = combineEpics(...epicsArr);
  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();
  const middleware = [epicMiddleware];
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
  );
  epicMiddleware.run(epics);
  return store;
};

export { configureStore };
```

And finally use my store here

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

import { configureStore } from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />,
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I really dont know what is going on, you have guys any idea? 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `default` case needs to be to change nothing, which is done by return the *current* state. Instead, you're replacing it with the initial state, thus overwriting the current state.

In other words, change this:

```
default:
  return initState;
```

to this:

```
default:
  return state;
```

You probably never encountered this before splitting up your reducers because you never entered the default case. Every possible action was accounted for in earlier lines of the `switch`. But now that some actions are deliberately not handled by this reducer, the default case is being executed.

Comment: Thank you very much , that was really dumb mistake, thank you very much